# c# TurnServer dynamic client connection

Tags: c#, stun, rfc5766turnserver

I have download [C# TurnServer](https://github.com/vf1/turnserver).

Please can someone can guide how to register and transfer data from clients how has Dynamic IP Address using turn server. I had spend couple of hours to find some help but no luck.

Please also guide for below.

1. if there any c# base any turn and stun server is available then please share url
2. if there is any free open source is available which support to webrtc then please share.

It would be great if someone can share knowledge, that may save my lots of hours.

thanks in advance.

Comment: c# is managed and the IP Header only allows certain protocols.  The protocols are the c# socket types.  Since c# doesn't support NAT you need to use a library like the one you are using. RFC 5766 is NAT Protocol.  The NAT uses a certificate and uses TLS for authentication.  I would start by using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to help debug.  I would check the version of TLS that is being used.  If it is TLS 1.0/1.1 then that is what is causing the issue.

Comment: The issue may be the SHA version in following : https://github.com/vf1/turnserver/blob/master/Turn.Server.Test/TurnServerTest.cs.  It is using SHA1 which is not supported in TLS 1.3.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please if there is any other sample available ? I have tried it but can't achieve result. e.g. I want to connect two clients and transfering data.

Comment: The term client and server have different meaning at application layer and socket layer.  When you have a socket one end is always a server and the other end is a client.  You have to start the server before the client.  At the application layer you can have two clients connected which is like a CHAT program, but the socket connection still has to be a client and server.